# Show text between 3 words on different lines from text with grep

Tags: grep

I want to show text between 3 words from text on 1 file:

```
lalala
<ticket>
BASH is awesome
BASH is awesome1
</ticket>
lalalala
<ticket>
BASH is awesome2
BASH is awesome3
texttext
</ticket>
lololo
<ticket>
awesome
BASH is awesome4
BASH is awesome5
</ticket>
lalalla
```

I try this:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)<ticket>.*\n.*awesome3.*\n.*</ticket>' file.txt
```

Result:

```
<ticket>
BASH is awesome
BASH is awesome1
</ticket>
lalalala
<ticket>
BASH is awesome2
BASH is awesome3
texttext
</ticket>
lololo
<ticket>
awesome
BASH is awesome4
BASH is awesome5
</ticket>
```

Expects:

```
<ticket>
BASH is awesome2
BASH is awesome3
texttext
</ticket>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following **grep** approach:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)<ticket>[^<>]*?awesome3.*?</ticket>' file.txt
```

The output:

```
<ticket>
BASH is awesome2
BASH is awesome3
texttext
</ticket>
```

---

`*?` - non-greedy modifier

Comment: Yeah thx! nice the non-greedy modifier. But why [^<>]?

Comment: @PGrill, welcome, `[^<>]` - to ensure that there are no nested tags